# Edit ViewGroup outside onCreate

Tags: java, android, view

I create a ViewGroup programatically. Then I add two Views, a game and a SeekBar. However, if I try to change the SeekBar properties from within the game (which has a pointer to the AndroidAdapter) using, for example, `parent.seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` the app crashes.

The parent filed is set as follows, inside game class:

```
public class Simulation extends ApplicationAdapter implements GestureDetector.GestureListener{

    AndroidLauncher parent=null;

    public void setParent( AndroidLauncher nparent ){
       parent = nparent;
    }

    public void something(){
        if( parent != null ) parent.layout.removeView( parent.seekBar );
    }
}
```

I'm I missing something like a permission to change the View? Do I have set/change something before editing the SeekBar? Thanks!

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

    Simulation simul;
    ViewGroup layout;

    SeekBar seekBar;
    ShapeDrawable thumb;
    LayoutParams lp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        simul = new Simulation();
        simul.setParent(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView( R.layout.main );
        layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById( R.id.panel );

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        config.useWakelock = true;
        config.useAccelerometer = false;
        config.useCompass = false;
        layout.addView(initializeForView(simul, config));


        seekBar = new SeekBar(this);
        seekBar.setMax(100);
        thumb = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        thumb.setIntrinsicHeight(50);
        thumb.setIntrinsicWidth(50);
        seekBar.setThumb(thumb);
        seekBar.setProgress(1);
        seekBar.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));
        lp = new LayoutParams(600, 50);
        seekBar.setLayoutParams(lp);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(".....111.......");
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(".....222.......");
            }

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(".....333......." + arg1);
            }
        });

        layout.addView(seekBar);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the exception you are getting

Comment: @r7v I does not say. I just says "uncaught exception".

Comment: you dont need special permission to build your own component . can you post the code , its hard to figure out with this ?

Comment: @r7v Added more code to original post.

Comment: whats AndroidApplication ? if you are tying to create a custom component just extend viewgroup or view

Comment: @r7v It a libGdx class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the main thread can edit the Views. To edit views from other classes, you must pass the reference to the main thread Class using something like `setParent(this)`. A callback method should be set in the main thread Class, this method will be called when you wish to edit the Views. In this method, you must guarantee that the instructions are executed by the main/UI thread, you can do this by using `runOnUiThread(...)`.

Check the following example:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

Simulation simul;
ViewGroup layout;

SeekBar seekBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    simul = new Simulation();
    simul.setParent(this);


    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById( R.id.panel );

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    config.useWakelock = true;
    config.useAccelerometer = false;
    config.useCompass = false;
    layout.addView(initializeForView(simul, config));

    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            System.out.println( progress );
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

}

public void showSeekBar(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            seekBar.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
        }
    });

}


public void hideSeekBar(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            seekBar.setVisibility( View.GONE );
        }
    });

}
```

The XML file is set as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main" android:orientation="vertical">



<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>


<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="406dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:progress="50"
    android:max="200"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
```